# replace bytes with strings using Replace()

Tags: c#, winforms

is it possible to replace bytes to chars in this method:

```
byte[] sttrings = new byte[pntrs[i + 1] - pntrs[i]];
stream.Position = pntrs[i];
stream.Read(sttrings, 0, sttrings.Length);
Strs[i] = Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS").GetString(sttrings).Split('\0')[0].Replace("[FF00]", "/et");
```

where 0x00FF (in hex editor it is FF 00) is the byte i want to replace with "/et"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the unicode char 0x00FF (`ÿ`) you just need to use the [Unicode escape character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx) `\uxxxx.

```
byte[] sttrings = new byte[pntrs[i + 1] - pntrs[i]];
stream.Position = pntrs[i];
stream.Read(sttrings, 0, sttrings.Length);
Strs[i] = Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS").GetString(sttrings).Split('\0')[0].Replace("[\u00FF]" , "/et");
```

If you really want to replace the byte values you may be able to use the [String constructor that takes in a char[]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx).

```
string replacementString = new String(new char[] {'[', '\0', (char)0xFF, ']'});
```

Comment: thank you sir :), but where do i put the string replacement ? before or after i get the strings ? or before reading ?